# facebook photos_addTag method doesnt work

Tags: php, facebook

how to add tag to facebook photo using php?

i have this code where `$pid` is id of photo , `$userId` is my facebook id.

sure i have use this before>

```
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
$test = $facebook->api_client->photos_addTag ($pid,$user_id, "text", 50.0, 50.0, '', $user_id);
```

`$test` returns 1

but photo is not tagged

can someone write me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm aware that you are using the old SDK, but how about using the new PHP-SDK **AND** the new graph api and just use the old rest `photos.addTag` inside the new SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //  tag photo parameter
  $pid = $uid.'_'.$pid; // pid is the photo id, after it uploaded, you need to add the owner id(uid) in front of it, and the real pid is inside the 'link' of the photo's returned json.
  //tag_uid = $uid;
  //x = percentage of x position
  //y = percentage of y position
  $access_token = $session['access_token'];

  $tag0 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd0,'x'=>'30.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag1 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd1,'x'=>'35.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag2 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd2,'x'=>'40.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag3 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd3,'x'=>'45.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag4 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd4,'x'=>'55.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag5 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd5,'x'=>'60.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag6 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd6,'x'=>'65.0','y'=>'85.0');
  $tag7 = array('tag_uid'=>$fd7,'x'=>'70.0','y'=>'85.0');

  $tags = array($tag0,$tag1,$tag2,$tag3,$tag4,$tag5,$tag6,$tag7);
  $facebook->api(array('method'=>'photos.addTag','pid'=>$pid,'tags'=>json_encode($tags)));
```

However, in the new facebook policy, they seems don't prefer apps to auto tag people on the photo anymore.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/photos/